# ¿Cómo puedo leer una variable tipo char con gets dentro de un switch?

Tags: c, condiciones

He estado probando leer una variable tipo `char` con el método `gets`. Lo puse dentro de un `switch` porque la idea del ejercicio es diferenciar entre el metodo `gets` y `scanf` . Éste es el código , a pesar de que compila no funciona.

Gracias de antemano.

```
            #include<stdio.h>
                int main(){
                int op;
                char nombre [30];
                    printf("1-Scanf \n\n2-Gets");
                    scanf("%i",&op);
                        switch(op){
                            case 1:printf("\nEscriba  su nombre metodo scanf\n");
                            scanf("%s",&nombre);
                            printf("\n\nSU NOMBRE ES %s",nombre);break;
                            case 2:printf("\nEscriba su nombre metodo gets\n");
                            gets(nombre);
                            printf("\nSu nombre es %s",nombre);break;
                                    }
                        }
```

Comment: Por qué dices que no funciona? QUé pasa cuando lo usas? Con qué dato pruebas? Qué debería hacer y no está haciendo?

Comment: Se supone que ,  en el case 2 , deberia de leer la variable nombre , cosa que no sucede , en vez de esto pasa directo, es decir imprime los dos printfs como si no existiera el gets.

Comment: No se recomienda el uso de la función `gets`y `scanf` para la lectura de cadenas. El motivo del porqué no se recomienda el uso de esas funciones, es porqué no pueden saber cual es el tamaño del arreglo y esto hace que ocasione un desbordamiento de búfer, haciendo que tu programa deje de funcionar si llegara a sobreescribir un espacio de memoria prohibida. Para su reemplazo use: [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hace tiempo me pasó lo mismo. Hay que borrar la basura (caracteres no imprimibles de salto de línea) del buffer de la entrada estandar.

```
 #include<stdio.h> 

int main(){
        int op;
        char nombre [30];
        printf("1-Scanf \n\n2-Gets");
        scanf("%i",&op);

        while ((getchar()) != '\n');

        switch(op){
                case 1:
                        printf("\nEscriba  su nombre metodo scanf\n");
                        scanf("%s",&nombre);
                        printf("\n\nSU NOMBRE ES %s",nombre);
                        break;

                case 2:
                        printf("\nEscriba su nombre metodo gets\n");
                        gets(nombre);
                        printf("\nSu nombre es %s",nombre);
                        break;
        }
}
```

Si te fijas sólo es añadir:

> while ((getchar()) != '\n');

después del `scanf`. De esta forma quitas el salto de línea que hacía que al llegar al `gets` cogiera el '\n' del `scanf` anterior..

Comment: Eso era muchas gracias